# write a template for md-menu, open it from different places on page at the right position

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a menu
 [image]

I want to open this menu from different places on the page, for example

[image]
[image]

What I want:
Everytime you click the plus sign on the gray background div or the line between two videos, the menu will pop up at the correct places, but the menu should only be written once as a template on the HTML, as I thought.

```
            <md-menu class="add-video">
         <!-- Trigger element is a md-button with an icon -->
         <md-button ng-click="$mdMenu.open($event)" class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Open sample menu">
           <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-home" class="icon vi-o2-1"></md-icon>
         </md-button>
         <md-menu-content>
           <md-menu-item>
             <md-button ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething()"><span class="icon vi-o2-1"></span>Add Videos</md-button>
           </md-menu-item>
           <md-menu-item>
             <md-button ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething()"><span class="icon vi-o2-1"></span>Semantic</md-button>
           </md-menu-item>
           <md-menu-item>
             <md-button ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething()"><span class="icon vi-o2-1"></span>Personalized</md-button>
           </md-menu-item>
           <md-menu-item>
             <md-button ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething()"><span class="icon vi-o2-1"></span>Nested Playlists</md-button>
           </md-menu-item>
         </md-menu-content>
        </md-menu>
```